MP3 "Info" header incorrect
I've come across an MP3 file (recorded news file at a radio station)  which calculates to 2:30 minutes in length when using the raw frame data, but the "Info" header calculates to 2:00 in length. My software reads the Info header if one exists as it could be a VBR file to ensure proper duration calculation. But other software including Windows File Properties shows the file at 2:30. The author of the file says the news is 2:00 long and they add a 30 second commercial to the end within an audio editor. Is it possible for an MP3 file to have 2 or more Info headers that should be read and accumulated?  Or is the software that created this file faulty?

"they add a 30 second commercial to the end" is perfectly possible by just adding MPEG frames at the end. Without a further "Info" frame, and without adjusting/overwriting existing "Info" frames in the original part of the new file. While "Info" frames can appear multiple times no software expects so and it is contrary to its intent anyway. The author might have binary merged both files - it doesn't even require any software that is MP3 related (copy /B news.mp + commercial.mp3 result.mp3).
